# Python Gtk Tutorial

Tags: python, gtk

This is example 2 from the GTK tutorial

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

   class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Hello World")

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

When I attempt to run, it displays nothing and when I close the window, I receive a message saying the program is still running.  I've stripped down the code and by eliminating the buttons, the window will appear so I think that there is a mistake in the button.add.

Comment: It works for me. Which platform are you using (Mac, Windows, Linux)?

Comment: Window 7, Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

In your code there was an unexpected indent error from the line containing 'class' and it didn't use the __name__ == '__main__' trick (though that's just a matter of good habit).

This should work. At least it does for Gtk+3 with Python 3.4 on my Ubuntu dist.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MyWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.  If I comment out the self.add(self.button) line, the window will appear with the title.  Otherwise the program displays nothing and I had to cance.

Comment: What do you get if you type the following?

Comment: print str.format("{0}.{1}", Gtk.get_major_version(), Gtk.get_minor_version())

Comment: I get a syntax error with the cursor between the str and the .

Comment: Oh I meant simply, what version of Gtk are you using? Type this into IDLE and you'll get the current version that's being loaded.

Comment: I typed it into idle and got a syntax error.  I did try just issuing a Print (Get.get.etc)  and major version is 3.  minor version returned 14.

Comment: @honestjohn Have you tried calling `self.show_all()` at the end if `__init__()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import from this way

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Hello World")

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Then use your ide for reindent all lines

if not work uninstall all your gtk modules, install this
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/
and try again